# Method didn't work in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hello
i put some uitextfield in uiscrollview,and connect them  in interface builder to event "touch down" to a method,the problem his that when the uitexttfield is inside uiscrollview the method doesn't called and when the textfield is not in the uiscroll view the method doesn't called.

Comment: Did you use an IBAction or what?

Comment: yes of course , it work when the uitextfield is not in the uiscroll view

Comment: Are you saying that neither the UITextField nor the UIScrollView are responding to touch events whether UITextField is contained in the UIScrollView or not? Is there a scenario when one of theses views do raise their respective touch events? I've noticed that if the top view receives and handles the touch, it won't propagate to the view below it. Depending on which view I want to respond, I'd sometimes set the userInteractionEnabled property to false

Comment: You should check the "User Interaction Enabled" property of all of the views you just described. Make sure it is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIScrollView is special because of all the touch events it needs to process itself. Try sub-classing UIScrollView and add:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
   NSLog(@"you should see this for touch events on your scroll view");
}
```

set the class name in IB to your UIScrollView subclass.